# Set #define in c code from Matlab

Tags: c, matlab

I have a Matlab program that uses and compiles C code. Now the C code uses a

```
defines.h
```

file containing all the defines for my source code. Now there is one define that is making trouble in Matlab and I would like to "deactivate" it whenever Matlab is compiling the .c files. I do not want to remove the define since I need it, when I compile my source code with gcc (without Matlab).
Is there any way to "redefine" a value within the compilation process in Matlab?

Here is a code snippet of my compilation process from Matlab:

```
mex CFLAGS='$CFLAGS -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -DMATLAB_MEX' function.c
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that in your `defines.h` you have a `#ifdef MATLAB_MEX` statement? This doesn't work?

Comment: Oh now I see, that it is obvious :) Didn't really think about it, but yes, that should work! Thanks for the hint :)!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have something like the following in `defines.h`

```
#ifndef MATLAB_MEX
  // code to "deactivate" when compling mex functions
#endif
```